# How to Modify a link in core php

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

Let the example be

I have a link:- `localhost/project/search?uni=1`

I want to change it in this way:- `localhost/project/search/uni-of-uk`

I am not using any framework , its a core PHP

Comment: how you come to know that `uni=1` i replaced by `uni-of-uk`

Answer (score 0):

Like this... based on the little info you gave ....

```
$link = 'localhost/project/search?uni=1';
$link = str_replace('?uni=1', '/uni-of-uk', $link);
```

**NEW:**  in PHP you can modify the header to change the url.

```
if($_GET['uni']==1)
{   header('Location: localhost/project/search/uni-of-uk');
    exit;
}
```

The important thing is that you DO NOT OUTPUT ANITHING before you call the header function.
So you should put this code on top of your script before any output.

Comment: how to change it in a URL ?

Comment: what do you mean ? you wont to change it in the browser location ? you wont to call the url with php ? please try to explain it better....

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `URL Rewriting`.

You can achieve this using `mod_rewrite` (assuming you are using apache).

You might want to look into this **[mod_rewrite Article](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)**

Answer (score 0):

If you meant you want to change

```
localhost/project/search?uni=1
```

to

```
localhost/project/search/uni-of-uk/1
```

You can achieve it by creating a **.htaccess** in your root folder and adding something like this to it,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?search/uni-of-uk/([0-9]+)$ /search?uni=$1
```

Another method is **PHP routing**, big CMS sites follow this method as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php).

Answer (score 0):

This can help you:

Write below code in your .htaccess file.

**RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+) search.php?uni=$1 [NC]**

Now, you can get value of "uni" using $_REQUEST['uni'] or $_GET['uni'] in your php file.